# Is it possible to enable render transparency for only certain renderlayers?

Tags: rendering, transparency, render-layers

I am currently rendering a scene that because of polycount issues I have to render on three different renderlayers. However I would like to disable the render transparency for one of those renderlayers. Is this possible?

Comment: A possible way is to split objects into several scenes, and in those render layers select which scene it's added from. One scene will use *Film* > *Transparent* while another one will not.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by assigning objects into different layers and setting render setting to transparent in the Scene setup property page.

Comment: Like the "environment" setting?